# How to configure Mosca for mqtts without the client having a certificate?

Tags: ssl, mqtt, mosca

I have a Mosca MQTT broker running on a node instance and I would like to encrypt all the incoming communications with SSL/TLS (MQTTs protocol) but without the client having to link any certificate to the connexion (I guess it has to do with self-signed certificates) just as https works. I want all my clients to connect just with credentials specifying the MQTTs protocol and the communication can be encrypted. I was using Amazon MQ just before and that's how it works so I want the same.

I can't figure how to configure properly Mosca to do so, I don't know what kind of certificate I must use.

- I added the secure field in the configuration as shown [here](https://github.com/mcollina/mosca/wiki/TLS-SSL-Configuration)
- For the certificate I tried to create a self signed certificate as shown [here](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_ssl)
- I also tried with certbot certificates (Let's Encrypt) registered for my domain name : mq.xxx.com .

I'm running everything on a ec2 (ubuntu 18) and my network and firewall are open for 1883 and 8883. My key and cert are at the root of my project where the deamon is running with good rights and ownership. I know my instance access them correctly.

```
new mosca.Server({
   port: 1883,
   secure: {
      keyPath: "./privkey.pem",
      certPath: "./cert.pem"
   },
   backend: {
      type: 'redis',
      redis: require('redis'),
      host: "localhost",
      port: 6379,
      db: 0,
      return_buffers: true,
   },
   persistence: {
      factory: mosca.persistence.Redis
   }
});
```

My server is running and working with simple mqtt on port 1883 but when I try to connect with ssl/tls with a client on port 8883 specifying that the server uses self-signed certificates (I tried with MQTT.fx) it fails saying : *"unable to find valid certification path to requested target"*.

I can't make my head around this issue, I think somehow the client cannot "accept" or "verify" the certificate provided. Maybe I'm providing the wrong key or certificate to Mosca but there is only one of each resulting openssl or certbot. Maybe I created wrong but I follow many tutorials on the very same subject such as [this one](https://books.google.fr/books?id=rvNFDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=mosca+ssl+certificates&source=bl&ots=Q6tzaSJDWn&sig=ACfU3U2TR_b6rMpjxopxL1z22HT-qNecMQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjB_M_jwLjhAhWF5OAKHT49DMsQ6AEwBHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=mosca%20ssl%20certificates&f=false)

What kind of certificate do I need to do ?

Is there something more to do with them ?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, sorry things are getting mixed up in my head as I overthink this simple problem. I edited my post to clarify my issue. I tried with different kind of certificates, from simple open-ssl self-signed to Let's encrypt ones. It always leads to the same error. I feel that I must use Let's encrypt certs since they have an international authority that my clients could know but every tutotials I have seen uses self-signed certificates with open-ssl. I feel that I must somehow specify to my clients wich CA I use but I guess it's embedded in my cert or key. I'm getting confused.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a self created certificate then the client will need a copy of certificate that signed the broker's certificate. This certificate will be added to the list of trusted sources so it can prove the broker is who it claims to be.

If you do not want to / can not distribute a certificate then you will need to use a certificate for your broker that is issued by CA (Certificate Authority) whoes signing certificate you already have (bundled into the OS/client that you are using).

The Lets Encrypt signing certificates should be bundled into most OSes by now but they are also cross signed by IdenTrust again who's certs should be bundled with most OSes. If you are having problems with the Lets Encrypt certs then I suggest you ask a new question with the exact details of how you configured mosca with those certs and more details of how you are configuring MQTT.fx and the errors you receive.

Comment: Ask a NEW question about Lets Encrypt Certificates